How do I make this Laravel Video watermark overlay function properly?
I have installed FFmpeg, and everything works and converts as I want it. However, when I tried with the watermark filter using the `ProtoneMediaLaravelFFMpegFiltersWatermarkFactory', it rendered without an issue, there is no watermark on it, and I cannot see any errors in the log file.
ConvertVideo.php
public function handle()
{
    $destination = '/' . $this->video->uid . '/' . $this->video->uid . '.m3u8';
    $low = (new X264('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(500);
    $high = (new X264('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(1000);

    FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos-temp')
        ->open($this->video->path)
        ->exportForHLS()
        ->addFormat($low, function ($filters) {
            $filters->resize(640, 480);
        })
        ->addFormat($high, function ($filters) {
            $filters->resize(1280, 720);
        })

       //watermark filter
        ->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
            $watermark->fromDisk('videos-temp')
                ->open('videos-temp/logo.png')
                ->right(-125)
                ->bottom(25)
                ->width(100)
                ->height(100);
        })
        
        ->toDisk('videos')
        ->save($destination);

    $this->video->update([
        'processed' => true,
        'proccessed_file' => $this->video->uid . '.m3u8'
    ]);
}

I can convert the videos without an issue, but I cannot put a watermark on them. How would you guys, 'EXPERTS', solve this?
The full code is posted above. I have added the following watermark filter.
// watermark filter
->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
    $watermark->fromDisk('videos-temp')
        ->open('videos-temp/logo.png')
        ->right(-125)
        ->bottom(25)
        ->width(100)
        ->height(100);
})

protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg - Github

Do you have a videos-temp folder inside your videos-temp disk? If not, try:->fromDisk('videos-temp')->open('logo.png'). Also, have you made sure the spatie/image package is installed?

Hey thanks for geting back to me, I did not install spatie/image, let me try it and see if works. Thanks again!

That might be it. According to the github page, you need it if you want to do watermark manipulation

set watermark file with absolute path like this:
->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
$watermark->fromDisk('videos-temp')
    ->open(storage_path('videos-temp/logo.png'))
    ->right(-125)
    ->bottom(25)
    ->width(100)
    ->height(100);
})


Thank brother hamid for taking time to answer. Let me try and see if its going to work.
